# Python: Xpath unable to get a number

Tags: python, xpath

I would like to get the info of '89.34' in the html

```
    <div class="MarketsTable-container-2b0AP KeyMetrics-table-Ow-Ln">
<table class="table-container two_columns MarketsTable-borderless-1FRfN MarketsTable-headerless-1ZF6D MarketsTable-condensed-2ragd">
<tbody><tr class="data"><th class="MarketsTable-label-_JI6s" cellPadding="1" cellSpacing="1" scope="row"><div class="TextLabel__text-label___3oCVw TextLabel__gray___1V4fk TextLabel__regular___2X0ym MarketsTable-label-_JI6s">P/E excl. Extra Items (Annual)</div></th>
<td class="MarketsTable-value-FP5ul" cellPadding="1" cellSpacing="1">
<span class="TextLabel__text-label___3oCVw TextLabel__black___2FN-Z TextLabel__regular___2X0ym digits MarketsTable-value-FP5ul">89.34</span></td></tr><tr class="data">
```

I try `xpath('//div[contains(., "P/E incl. Extra Items (TTM)")]/following-sibling::td[1]/text()')`but return nothing.
Please advise.
The url is as below
https://www.reuters.com/companies/AALI.JK/key-metrics

Comment: Your html is invalid; please edit the question.

Comment: @JackFleeting, sorry, I may not copy the whole html but I put the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below xpath.

```
//div[contains(., 'P/E incl. Extra Items (TTM)')]/../following-sibling::td[1]/span/text()
```

or you can use parent::th

```
//div[contains(., 'P/E incl. Extra Items (TTM)')]/parent::th/following-sibling::td[1]/span/text()
```

[image]